# Display item in HTML from an object in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I'm having some trouble displaying retrieved JSON data that I've put into an object in HTML in Angular.

I can see the JSON in the console, and I have put the JSON data into an object array but I cannot get the data to display from the array in the HTML.

Here's the TS I use to pull the data and put it into an object array

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-venue-details-db',
  templateUrl: './venue-details-db.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venue-details-db.component.css']
})

export class VenueDetailsDbComponent implements OnInit {


  postData = {
    command: 'get_lakeDetails',
  }
  
  url = "http://cot******.co.uk:8443"

  json: any;
  
  venues2: Object[] = [];

  venues: any; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.post<JSON>(this.url, this.postData).toPromise().then((data) => {
      this.json = data;
      this.venues2 = [];
      console.log("feature post attempt made")
      console.log("this is the data", data)
      console.log(typeof data)

      Object.entries(data).forEach(venue => {
          console.log("Object log", venue[1][0]);
          //let venueData = (name: "", descriptin: "");
          var venueData = {"name": venue[1][0], "locale": venue[1][1], "type": venue[1][2], "availability": venue[1][3], "pricing": venue[1][4], "imgurl": "assets/img/Prison 1.jpg", "desc": venue[1][5], "overview": venue[1][6]};

          this.venues2.push(venueData);
  
      });

      this.venues = (this.venues2);



      console.log("venues", this.venues)
      console.log("json log", this.json)
      console.log(this.venues.name)
      //this.venues2 = data
    });
  } //constructor end

 
   //venues: any = (data as any).default;

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  }

}
```

And here is the HTML, I can get the JSON to display but I can't get items for objects in the array. Must be doing something silly, because I can see it in the console.

```
<pre>
  {{ json | json }}
</pre>

<div *ngFor="let items of venues">{{venues.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by building an interface or class for your object

```js
export class VenuesInfo {
   venueId: number; 
   name: string;
   // any other needed attributes
}
```

Then update your TS file with the following

```js
json: any;
  
venues: VenuesInfo[] = [];
```

Make sure to build your class based off of the data being returned from the API and your HTML should be updated to this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of venues">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake in your code there, on the HTML. Instead of writing `venues.name` it should be `items.name`

Like this

```
<div *ngFor="let items of venues">{{items.name}}</div>
```